# Regex search for a fixed string that could have non-alphanumeric characters inside the string

Tags: regex

I am trying to find a specific string (invoice number) like: `VFE033586` inside a digitized invoice (raw text), but some customers use hyphens inside those invoice numbers like: `VFE-033586`.

Is there a possibility to create a regex expression that can use the original string without modifying it, so, it finds even if there is a hyphen in the raw text invoice? Like ignoring non-alphanumeric character.

I've tried to search, but did not come up with anything similar.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
[A-Z]+-?[0-9]+
```

or more general with groups: `([A-Z]+)[\W]?([\d]+)`

Example: https://regex101.com/r/oelSH0/2

Comment: I cant use general search strings.. I need to look for exact string.. It is digitized invoice, there is more than 10000 characters in it and I need to confirm if the invoice number exists in the raw text.

Comment: is your invoice always 3 capital case letters followed by 6 digits with optional symbol in the middle?

Comment: unfortunately not, it can be absolutely anything, every customer has different formats, that is why the only way is to have a fixed string for search. If regex does not have some sort of ignore, it probably is not possible without modifying the original string. I have a way if i modify it, but it takes time to code, which i dont have.. hoped there is a way in regex, but if not, no big deal.. thanks anyways